# How can I redirect to a view in another application and still pass arguments (Django)

Tags: python, django, url, redirect, view

Another question like this one was asked, but I don't 'like' the answer (in reality it didn't really answer the question in the first place): [Can any one explain how can i pass arg or kwargs from redirect to another view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581351/can-any-one-explain-how-can-i-pass-arg-or-kwargs-from-redirect-to-another-view))

I have a view and need to redirect to another view (in another application) and still send an argument along. Currently I have:

```
return redirect('/projects/', login_error=error)
```

Which doesn't work (the redirect happens but the argument doesn't go through). Is it even possible to do this using `redirect()`? The documentation doesn't have anything on it.

However, I also tried referring to the view without using a URL:

```
return redirect('projects.views.list_all', login_error=error)
```

But that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) returns an HTTP redirect to the supplied URL - that is, the browser receives a 
 30x response and initiates a new request.

To preserve state between the two requests, you either need to set a session variable (as per the other answer) or provide a query parameter, eg:

```
return redirect('/projects/?login_error=error')
```

You will then need to process the incoming `request.GET` parameter in the other view.

Comment: I see, that makes more sense. However, the docs do say that if you refer to the view itself (and not the URL), you can safely pass arguments (source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.redirect). How would I refer to a view outside the current app?

Comment: The view name is still used to get the URL - the kwargs are regular expression parameters for URLs, not method arguments for the view.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I guess I'm using session variables after all.

Comment: Any particular reason you need to go to that URL though? Usually a specific 'login error' page/view is more appropriate, and you can keep all you login handling in one place.

Comment: I'm trying to get a nice alert on the page itself (the index page), instead of redirecting the user to another login page. Just personaly preference really.

Comment: Ah - ok then, yes a session var is the best way. Good luck :)